# Starting Rails server issue - Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, ruby-on-rails-5, jenkins-pipeline

We are starting integrate our build and automation testing process to jenkins pipeline, and I have some issue with starting rails server.
First of all, this is our pipeline chart: [image]

In any step of "Config" (0,1,2), I start different rails app with specific port, using: `rails s -p XXXX -d`, and just after the execution command, I run `lsof -i:XXXX` and I DO see the server running.

But, in QA stage, I want to use the servers I ran in Servers Configuration stage, but I get connection refused in our tests, and also, when accessing the server the apps ran on, I don't see them running anymore, even that I used -d to daemonize them.
Any ideas? it seems like the rails servers ran only for the servers configuration stage and then closed, is that possible? and if so, how do I handle them?
Thanks!